# Ajuda para descobrir raiz quadrada de um número positivo em Python

Tags: python

Sou iniciante em Python e estou fazendo alguns exercícios para aprender mais sobre a referida linguagem. Em uma questão, foi solicitado que criasse um programa que solicitasse um número e devolvesse a raiz quadrada do mesmo. E necessariamente se esse número fosse negativo, uma mensagem de erro deveria ser apresentada.

Consegui fazer o código funcionar através da biblioteca "math", mas, logo ao pedir o número, meu programa responde com um "none", que não sei como retirá-lo. Segue meu código e, desde já, obrigado:

````
n = int(input(print('Digite um número:')))
if n < 0:
   print('Número inválido.')
else:
   raiz = math.sqrt(n)
   print(f'A raiz quadrada de {n} é {raiz}')  ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não precisa daquele "print" dentro do input

```
n = int(input(print('Digite um número:')))
```

Segue abaixo a maneira correta:

```
n = int(input('Digite um número:'))
```

O código completo, caso queira:

```
import math

n = int(input('Digite um número:'))

if n < 0:
    print('Número inválido.')
else:
    raiz = math.sqrt(n)
    print(f'A raiz quadrada de {n} é {raiz}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Neste código existem dois erros. O primeiro se refere à função **print** na linha do código do **input()** - você deve retirá-lo. E o segundo erro foi que você chamou a biblioteca **math** sem importá-la anteriormente - neste caso, você precisa importar a biblioteca **math**.

Outra coisa, se estiveres utilizando **python 3.8 ou superior** podes deixar o código mais conciso utilizando os conceitos de **[Assignment Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions)**.

Pois bem, dessa forma podemos implementar o seguinte código:

```
from math import sqrt

while (n := int(input('Digite um número inteiro: '))) < 0:
    print('Valor INVÁLIDO!')

print(f'A raiz quadrada de {n} é: {sqrt(n):.2f}')
```

Observe que quando executamos este código recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite um número inteiro:` . Neste momento devemos digitar um número inteiro e pressionar <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

A partir deste momento o bloco **while** verificará se o valor atribuído à variável **n** é menor que **0**. Caso positivo - o valor sendo de fato um número negativo - será exibido a mensagem **Valor INVÁLIDO!** e, caso contrário, será calculada a raiz quadrada de n, sendo em seguida exibido o valor de n, bem como o valor de sua raiz.

Observe que também podemos resolver esta questão sem ter de importar a biblioteca math. Para isso basta escrevermos a operação de raiz quadrada no código.

**OBSERVAÇÃO:**

A raiz quadrada de x é: x ** (1/2).

Desta forma o código ficará:

```
while (n := int(input('Digite um número inteiro: '))) < 0:
    print('Valor INVÁLIDO!')

print(f'A raiz quadrada de {n} é: {n ** (1 / 2):.2f}')
```

Observe também que nem todo **quadrado** é um **quadrado perfeito**. Portanto, nem toda raiz quadrada será inteira. Por isso, implementei em ambos os códigos o arredondamento do valor da raiz quadrada para **duas casas decimais**.